# How to force WCF service use only one thread?

Tags: wcf

I need to force my WCF service running in a single thread due to the inner action depends on a legacy COM object which doesn't support multi-thread call.

Then I wrote the following sample code, but it doesn't work as I expected :(

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void TestAction();
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode =     ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public class TestServiceImp : ITestService
{
    void TestAction()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Entering method TestAction, Thread={0}" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        //...
        Trace.WriteLine("Leaving method TestAction, Thread={0}" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

The real result is something like the following,

*Entering method TestAction, Thread=4*

*Leaving method TestAction, Thread=4*

*Entering method TestAction, Thread=5*

*Leaving method TestAction, Thread=5*

*Entering method TestAction, Thread=8*

*Leaving method TestAction, Thread=8*

while my expectation is,

*Entering method TestAction, Thread=4*

*Leaving method TestAction, Thread=4*

*Entering method TestAction, Thread=4*

*Leaving method TestAction, Thread=4*

*Entering method TestAction, Thread=4*

*Leaving method TestAction, Thread=4*

How could I get what I want? Thanks.

Comment: May I suggest this answer to a nearly identical question: [c# - Force WCF to use one thread - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000078/force-wcf-to-use-one-thread/20010432#comment51204132_20010432)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a service with InstanceContextMode to "Single" just means that every calls from different clients will be execute on the same instance, but the thread responsible of the execution is managed by the thread-pool.

Basically if you use a concurrency mode "Single" (the default configuration) for each call a thread will be take from thread-pool, used and then give back to it, so it could be possible that the thread is the same but it can't be guaranteed

If you want to manage the access to a non thread-safe resource you should do it manually, to define which thread will be execute your service instance, you have instead to work with a 
SynchronizationContext

http://nevmehta.blogspot.ch/2006/12/what-is-usesynchronizationcontext.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx

Hope this helps
Marco

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Thread Affinity Synchronization Context described in [Synchronization Contexts in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163321.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Another good resource from Microsoft:

[Concurrency Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596521301-02-08.aspx)

In my case I ended up by using a lock based on the service type:

```
lock (typeof(MyServiceType)) {
...
}
```

Be careful when setting Single ConcurrencyMode on a WCF service that uses EntityFramework context, because the service and its resources won't be disposed until the thread is killed, what can end up in non updated data on read operations.