# Complete operation in the same UI thread with synchronization context

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, task-parallel-library

From UI (**thread1**) I want to create a progress UI(**thread2**).
Progress UI creates a task in **thread3** and waits for its completion.

The task(**thread3**) completes and invoke closing of progress UI which must be executed in **thread2**.

For closing operation I use AsyncOperationManager to capture context of thread2 and then execute POST method from **thread4**.

But closing always happens from some another thread.

All the code below is from ProgressWindows class.

```
_currentTask = new Progress<double>(Close); // I call this in progress UI constructor.

// This is invoked in constructor of Progress class which is used inside ProgressWindow.
_asyncOperation = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);

public static void Run2(Action action) 
{ 
    Debug.WriteLine(":: Run2 in thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); 

    var th = new Thread(_ => 
    { 
        Debug.WriteLine(":: StartNew in thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); 
        var progress = new ProgressWindow(); 
        progress.Run(action); 
    }); 

    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); 
    th.Start(); 
} 


 public void Run(Action action) 
 { 
    Debug.WriteLine(":: Run in thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); 

    SetupProgressBar(); 
    RunTask(action); 

    ShowDialog(); 
} 

private void RunTask(Action action) 
{ 
    Task.Factory.StartNew(action).ContinueWith(_ => _currentTask.OnCompleted(null)); 
} 

private void Close(object state) 
{ 
    Debug.WriteLine(":: Close in thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); 

    Hide(); 
    Close(); 
}
```

The question is:

```
private void RunTask(Action action) 
{ 
    Task.Factory.StartNew(action).ContinueWith(_ => _currentTask.OnCompleted(null)); 
}
```

You see, `_currentTask.OnCompleted(null)` is invoked from another thread, but `_currentTask`of type Progress uses context captured in the UI thread, but `OnCompleted`is always invoked from another thread other than UI thread. Why? It must be in the same context.

**Update 1:**

Mixing **System.Threading.SynchronizationContex**t with **System.Windows.Form.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext** and **System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext**

Comment: You're calling `ContinueWith` from a background thread. Why would you assume it would marshal it to the UI thread?

Comment: Because within the scope of ProgressWindow I create Progress where I create asyncOperation with AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation. And I call OnCompleted with asyncOperation.Post. Definitely, this is the same UI context... I suppose so.

Comment: All is fixed with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, but I wonder why SynchronizationContext is a miss here?

Comment: Not sure, not familiar with `AsyncOperationManager`.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14265/The-NET-Framework-s-New-SynchronizationContext-Cla

Comment: Though, I admit that the article above is contradictory.
This may as well be that SyncContext is not appropriate to marshal code to the main UI thread: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I

Comment: IMHO, the progress UI should be in the same thread with the original UI. Each new thread just makes things more complicated. In any case, I would also use the async/await pattern for dealing with managing continuations that need to happen on captured thread contexts. That's what it's there for. Otherwise, you're just going to be rewriting what Microsoft's already done for you.

Comment: Peter, I would use the async/await, but we can't move to 4.5 right now. I agree with the position that this should be the same thread as the main UI thread, because work is done in the background. But what if background intensly update UI? It may freeze the progress as well. In this case I would recommend using another thread for progress. The solution I've come to is to create Progress<T> instance in the same thread with creating the instance of ProgressWindow UI,  because in this case AsyncOperationManager capture DispatcherSynchronizationContext instead of ThreadSynchronizarionContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Synchronization context in asynchronous WCF per call service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038370/synchronization-context-in-asynchronous-wcf-per-call-service)

[Force WCF to use one thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000078/force-wcf-to-use-one-thread/20010432#20010432)

**AsyncOperationManager** works differently depending on context where **AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation** was invoked.
Denending on context, **AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation** may create three contexts:

*System.Threading.SynchronizationContext
System.Windows.Form.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext*

In my case when I capture context before ShowDialog, I capture thread sync context, 
but if I invoke AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation within OnLoad event, I capture
System.Windows.Form.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext or DispatcherSynchronizationContext 
depending on WindowsForms or WPF is used. That was the source of error.

I would cut it down to just using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke. 
But to leave all the code with Progress, I just placed AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation and creating new background thread inside OnLoad of ProgressWindow UI. It has resolved the issue.